# bash-команда для замены всех вхождений в файле на нулевые байты

Tags: файлы, bash, sh

Есть файл, допустим, `example_file`, допустим, двоичный.

Я хочу заменить все вхождения в него строк `example_str`, на соответствующую последовательность нулевых байтов (`\0`), то есть чтобы каждый символ во вхождении был заменён на нулевой байт. (специально указывать `\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0` - не вариант, потому что (1) это неудобно, (2) я хотел бы использовать эту команду не один раз для разных строк)

Какой `bash`-командой это можно было бы сделать? Хотелось бы как можно короче и проще.

Comment: Команда — например python) Только к этой команде нужно дописать небольшой скрипт, строк 10. И все достаточно просто и читаемо будет, без всякой эзотерики.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### 1. Нашёл такое решение:

```
python -c "n='example_file';r=b'example_str';f=open(n,'r+b');d=f.read().replace(r,b'\0'*len(r));f.seek(0);f.write(d)"
```

Вот такой же код, но в более читаемом виде:

```
file_name = 'example_file'
to_replace = b'example_str'
f = open(file_name, 'r+b')
data = f.read().replace(to_replace, b'\0' * len(to_replace))
f.seek(0)
f.write(data)
```

Так как файл двоичный, используется символ `b` перед строкой `example_str`. Это может быть необязательно, если `unicode`-строка удовлетворяет требованиям.

##### 2. Также [на англоязычной версии сайта мне подсказали другое решение](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77740665/11631959):

```
perl -0777spe'BEGIN { $r = "\0" x length($s) } s/\Q$s/$r/g' -i -- -s=example_str example_file
```

Или, если покороче:

```
perl -0777spe'BEGIN{$r="\0"x length($s)}s/\Q$s/$r/g' -i -- -s=example_str example_file
```

Если `example_str` содержит специальные символы, то необходимо задать её в коде, например, для строки `\0\1\2`:

```
perl -0777spe'BEGIN{$s="\0\1\2";$r="\0"x length($s)}s/\Q$s/$r/g' -i -- example_file
```

Для строк с особыми символами, но без нулевых символов (с кодом 0), можно использовать `printf`:

```
perl -0777spe'BEGIN{$r="\0"x length($s)}s/\Q$s/$r/g' -i -- -s=$(printf "\1\2\3\1\2\3") example_file
```

Answer (score 0):

Используйте `sed`:

```
$ echo a | sed 's/./b/g'
b

$ echo aaa | sed 's/./b/g'
bbb
```

Для изменения файла добавьте sed'у ключ `-i`.

Дополнение после коментария, возьмем такой файл:

```
$ cat f
asdasd
asdas
test
asdad
asfasf
testtest
sdas
asda
test
```

И попробуем изменить все 'test' на что-нибудь:

```
$ sed '/test/s//AAAAAA/g' f
asdasd
asdas
AAAAAA
asdad
asfasf
AAAAAAAAAAAA
sdas
asda
AAAAAA
```

Comment: Это заменит все символы в файле на заданные. А мне нужно заменить только вхождение определённой строки. И заменить нужно на нулевые символы. По представленным вами командам я не могу понять, как это сделать.

Comment: Я просто подтолкнул вас в правильном направлении этим примером, добавил более развернутый ответ.